# If statement in zoo series when adding a column

Tags: r, if-statement, zoo

I have the following zoo series:

```
head(prices.zoo)

         JetFuel HeatingOil  Spread
Sep 1996   0.682     0.6794  0.0026
Oct 1996   0.703     0.7307 -0.0277
Nov 1996   0.696     0.7261 -0.0301
Dec 1996   0.693     0.7171 -0.0241
Jan 1997   0.680     0.7142 -0.0342
Feb 1997   0.619     0.6081  0.0109
```

My goal is to add a 4th column **Action** that has 1 when **Spread**>0 and -1 when Spread<0. I tried the following code:

```
f <-function(x){ 
if(x>0) y=1 
else y= -1
return(y)}

prices.zoo$Action <- sapply(prices.zoo$Spread,f)
```

A warning message popped up: "Warning message:
In if (x > 0) y = 1000 else y = -100 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" 
And the result is obviously incorrect:

```
         JetFuel HeatingOil  Spread Action
Sep 1996   0.682     0.6794  0.0026      1
Oct 1996   0.703     0.7307 -0.0277      1
Nov 1996   0.696     0.7261 -0.0301      1
Dec 1996   0.693     0.7171 -0.0241      1
Jan 1997   0.680     0.7142 -0.0342      1
Feb 1997   0.619     0.6081  0.0109      1
```

But after I converted the zoo series to a data frame, everything worked:

```
prices.zoo.df <- data.frame(prices.zoo)
prices.zoo.df$Action <- sapply(prices.zoo.df$Spread,f) 
head(prices.zoo.df)

         JetFuel HeatingOil  Spread Action
Sep 1996   0.682     0.6794  0.0026      1
Oct 1996   0.703     0.7307 -0.0277     -1
Nov 1996   0.696     0.7261 -0.0301     -1
Dec 1996   0.693     0.7171 -0.0241     -1
Jan 1997   0.680     0.7142 -0.0342     -1
Feb 1997   0.619     0.6081  0.0109      1
```

Could anyone please explain to me why this is the case? Is there any way to achieve the same thing on the zoo series without moving to the data frame?

**Reproducible Example**

```
z <- zoo(cbind(c1 = c(1,2,3,-1,-2)),Sys.Date()+0:4)

f <-function(x){ 
if(x>0) y=1 
else y= -1
return(y)}

z$c2 <- sapply(z$c1,f)
```

^This method with sapply produces the following output (not what I am looking for):

```
           c1 c2
2017-05-09  1  1
2017-05-10  2  1
2017-05-11  3  1
2017-05-12 -1  1
2017-05-13 -2  1
```

After the above zoo series gets converted to a data frame the same method with sapply works:

```
z <- data.frame(z)
z$c2 <- sapply(z$c1,f)
z

           c1 c2
2017-05-09  1  1
2017-05-10  2  1
2017-05-11  3  1
2017-05-12 -1 -1
2017-05-13 -2 -1
```

Comment: You probably want to use `ifelse` instead of `if`. See `?ifelse`.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. It worked: prices.zoo$Action <- ifelse(prices.zoo$Spread>0,1,-1)

Comment: Do you also happen to know why I could use the if statement in a data frame but not in a zoo series? Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, but maybe use `lapply` to run through the variables of the data.frame. There are plenty of answers on SO that relate to this method.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example that we can just copy and paste into R. Show output of `dput(head(prices.zoo))`.  The warning message you got (it's not an error message) suggests that your setup is not as decribed in the question.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: This is the output: structure(c(0.682, 0.703, 0.696, 0.693, 0.68, 0.619, 0.6794, 
0.7307, 0.7261, 0.7171, 0.7142, 0.6081, 0.00260000000000005, 
-0.0277000000000001, -0.0301, -0.0241, -0.0341999999999999, 0.0109
), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("JetFuel", "HeatingOil", 
"Spread")), index = structure(c(1996.66666666667, 1996.75, 1996.83333333333, 
1996.91666666667, 1997, 1997.08333333333), class = "yearmon"), class = "zoo")

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: To hopefully make my question clearer, I added a reproducible example in my post. I was just confused over how the if statement+sapply approach works with a data frame but not with a zoo series. Now that it is clear ifelse is the way to go, that question is more or less trivial I guess. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these would work:

```
# 1
prices.zoo$Action <- sign(prices.zoo$Spread)

# 2
prices.zoo$Action <- (prices.zoo$Spread > 0) - (prices.zoo$Spread < 0)

# 3
prices.zoo$Action <- ifelse(prices.zoo$Spread > 0, 1, -1)

# 4
prices.zoo$Action <- sapply(coredata(prices.zoo$Spread), f)
```

Normally we would not use `sapply` unless the problem cannot be vectorized without it.